# How to give a small horizontal space between each point in ListPlot variants?

Tags: plotting

How to give a small horizontal space between each point in ListPlot variants?

I'm trying to create a graph with error bars by `ErrorListPlot` which is a function in `ErrorBarPlots` context.

The data I want to show can be downloaded from my dropbox:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/95sk278drhfl2hj/sampleData.dat?dl=0
You might face a problem when `Import` the above data that the elements at level three are not recognized correctly. Sorry but I don't know how to resolve it.

The structure of the data is:
Dimension[data]={7, 37, 2},
data[[1,2]]={20., 2.76131}.

Anyway, straightforwardly, the following command gives me a plot as follows:

```
    ErrorListPlot[data,
                  PlotRange -> {-80, 80},
                  GridLines -> Automatic,
                  PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> 15],
                  ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: the output]

The resulting graph is good other than that, many points and error bars are overlaid with each other and we hardly can see the detail for points behind.

My idea to resolve this problem is to give a small horizontal space for each data point so that they can be seen separately. I, however, don't know how to realize it.

Does any of you guys know how to realize it?
Or some other clever way to make it readable is also welcome.

I use Mathematica ver.11.1.1.0.

Thank you in advance.

---

P.S.

At first, the permission of the link to my dropbox was inappropriate and nobody can download it. Now I change it and anyone can download it. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: can you post `Dimension[data]` and `data[[1,2]]` for `data` in your `ErrorListPlot[data,...]`?

Comment: Try saving your data as `.csv` rather than `.dat`

Comment: Please see https://medium.com/nightingale/improve-your-visualization-skills-using-tuftes-principles-of-graphical-design-3a0f40a53a2c and related topics.  Your graph (even with horizontal spacing) is currently close to unintelligible.

Comment: @kglr Dimension[data]={7, 37, 2}, data[[1,2]]={20., 2.76131}

Comment: @BobHanlon `.csv` didn't resolve it. I don't know how to export data as preserving the structure with more than three levels.

Comment: @JimB I understand.

Comment: The answer from @kglr does exactly (and very nicely) what you requested but I think because you have 37 different sets of 7, you might have to split the 37 sets into 3 or 4 smaller sets to make the figures readable.

Comment: @JimB Actually, the data is 7 different sets of 37 data points. Anyway, a smaller number of sets is better to show in a plot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, based on the picture in OP, a simple data set that reproduces the issue in OP:

```
SeedRandom[1]
epdata = Table[Table[{RandomReal[1], RandomReal[0.5]}, {i, 10}], 5];

Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]

elp = ErrorListPlot[epdata, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1 + Length@epdata[[1]]}, {-1/2, 3/2}}, 
  PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[Automatic],
  ImageSize -> Large, 
  GridLines -> {1/2 + Range[0, 1 + Length@epdata[[1]]], None}]
```

[image]

Define a helper function that produces a list of x-coordinate displacements so that `n` points with shared x-coordinate `x0` are equally spaced in the interval from `x0 - width/2` to `x0 + width / 2`:

```
ClearAll[xDisplacements]
xDisplacements[width_: 1/3] := Subdivide[-width/2, width/2, Length[#] - 1] &


translations = Thread[{xDisplacements[][epdata], 0}];
```

Post-process `elp` to translate points and lines using `translations`:

```
ReplaceAll[prims : {_Point, ___} :> 
   Translate[prims, Last[translations = RotateLeft[translations]]]] @ elp
```

[image]

Use `translations = Thread[{xDisplacements[1/4][epdata], 0}];` above to get

[image]